# Cannot find name 'Http' in Angular 10

Tags: angular, typescript, http, templates, angular10

I want to render external input template in my Angular Component. However 'http' is not found. I have also installed @types/node in the project but that has not resolved the dependency.

I am trying to set it via this code:

```
<div style="height: 300px;">
    <div [innerHTML]="stepTemplate"></div>
</div>
```

---

```
setView() {
   const temp =  this.inputModel.templateUrl;
   this.stepTemplate = this.http.get(temp).map((html: any) => this.stepTemplate = html);
}
```

---

```
import * as Http from 'http';    
export class JourneyLineComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    
        .....
        http: Http;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is what you want for your import

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

Angular switched over to HttpClient from Http a few versions back

also, you want to inject that into your constructor so

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}